# Exploring Overfit of model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I m detecting a overfit for my deep-learning model.

But I m confused about overfitting.

For example, my training accuracy and loss are high, my development loss and accuracy are almost equal to it.

Questions;

i) What does this mean?

ii) What actions should I do?

iii) What are the possible results for the actions?

Comment: if your training loss and training accuracy is equal to the development accuracy and development loss than this is not overfitting. Will you please share the values of loss and accuracy..

Comment: What is the name of that if this occures? I will share.

Comment: There are a lot of things. that you are not giving enough data to the model or their be some tuning required and many more. share more things so that we can go specific

Comment: train loss and train accuracy result is high. Also development loss and accuracy are the same value. what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's very simple concept to find whether your model is overfitting as taught by Professor Andrew Ng

If there's much difference between your training set accuracy and your development set accuracy then that means your model is overfitting your training data and you can do different things like

1.) Introduce L2 regularization

2.) Introduce dropout in the network(or increase the network dropout probability)

3.) Try adding more data if possible in your training set which is a representative of the data you might be using in your dev or test set.

4.) Try to change your neural network architecture.

5.) You can introduce random noise in your data (Data Augmentation).

If there's not much difference between your training data and your development data accuracy, then the network is not overfitting the data.

Comment: So do you also define this situation as overfit?

Comment: @Daniels you can mention your accuracies, then I can tell you more about it.

Comment: training loss: 80 training accuracy: 85
development loss and accuracy : 75

Comment: There's case of overfitting according to me since accuracy difference is around 10% so you can try to follow above mentioned steps. Or you can try tuning hyperparameters.